# evento ckick con unico ID en el DOM

Tags: jquery

Estimados, les quiero comentar que tengo una lista de elementos html generados mediante un bucle (while) desde PHP (todos tienen el mismo ID y CLASS). El problema que tengo es que le quiero asignar un evento click desde jquery a esos elementos. Mediante el ID, claramente no funciona según las especificaciones técnicas de JQUERY ya que el el DOM el ID debe ser único; mediante CLASS funciona pero llama  el evento a todos los elementos a la vez, por mas que le haga click solamente a uno (ya que todos comaprten el mismo class). Así es que ando enredado en este problema, si alguien tiene un aporte para darme, se lo agradezco desde ya. 
paso a dejar el código jquery:

```
        document.querySelectorAll(".elemento")
          $("#comentar").click(function(){
          $(".elemento").show();
         });
```

Acá pongo resumido el código que utilizo en el bucle:

```
<?php while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
<div id="hola" class="mundo"><?php echo ver[0];?></div>
 <?}>
```

Salu2!!!!

Comment: Hola Santiago ayudaría que compartieras también un ejemplo del código html que te genera el código php

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, ¿El click lo haces sobre el elemento? Si es así, ¿has probado a referenciar con $(this)?

Comment: ahí modifique la pregunta. El tema esta en que la lista de elementos generados mediante php tienen un mismo ID y un mismo CLASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que tu error esté en querer encerrar los listeners dentro de `document.querySelectorAll`.

Si como dices, quieres, asignar un id a cada elemento y escuchar los clicks de ese elemento, la mejor manera sería encerrar todo el código dentro de `$(function() {`, es la función que permite que todo el DOM esté listo y luego puedes escuchar por id, por clase, o por lo que quieras.

Aquí te dejo varios ejemplos:

```js
$(function() {

    /*Selector por id y elemento*/
    $("#test1 p").on('click', function() {
      $(this).slideUp();
    });

    /*Selector por clase y elemento*/
    $(".test2 p").click(function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });

    /*Selector por clase, cualquier elemento*/
    $(".test3").click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });

    /*Selector por id*/
    $("#test4").click(function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
  <p>Me iré para arriba si haces clic en mi</p>
  <p>También me iré para arriba si haces clic en mi</p>

  <hr />

</div>
<div class="test2">
  <p>Me pondré rojo si haces clic en mi</p>
  <p>Me pondré también rojo si haces clic en mi</p>

  <hr />

</div>
<div class="test3">
  <p>Yo y mi botón nos quitaremos lentamente de tu vista si haces clic en mí</p>
  <button>Hazme invisible junto con el texto de arriba</button>
</div>

<hr />
<p id="test4">Soy único, seré un pitufo  si haces clic en mi</p>
```

---

#### PHP: Asignar ids diferentes

Modifica tu PHP así.

Es todo código PHP, sin mezcla con código HTML. El código es más legible así.

```
<?php 

$strHTML="";
$i=1;
while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){  
    $strDivId="hola".$i; 
    $strHTML.='<div id="'.$strDivId.'" class="mundo">'.$ver[0].'</div>';
    $i++;
}
echo $strHTML;

?>
```

Tendrás cada `div` que se crea dentro del bucle con un id distinto:

```
<div id="hola1">...</div>
<div id="hola2">...</div>
<div id="hola3">...</div>
....
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar! el problema es que el bucle en php me genera elementos con el mismo id y el mismo class. De ahí que no pueda discriminar cada elemento desde la función javascript. Intente asignar números aleatorios a los ID de cada elemento generado, pero tampoco tuve resultados.

Comment: @SantiagoGonzalez es evidente que si quieres alcanzar cada elemento por separado debes asignar un id distinto a cada elemento y luego alcanzarlo mediante `#id-elemento`, como muestro en el último ejemplo de la respuesta: `/*Selector por id*/` El problema es entonces el código con el que generas los elementos... Y no tendrían que ser ids aleatorios, pues el azar puede hacer que varios elementos adquieran el mismo id, lo que tendrías que hacer es crear un bucle incremental, y asignar a cada elemento un id basado en el índice del bucle. Muestra el código donde generas los elementos.

Comment: gracias Cedano, tienes razón respecto a ids al azar. Ahí edite la pregunta  así se ve resumidamente como aplico el código php.

Comment: @SantiagoGonzalez he puesto al final de la respuesta una forma de generar el HTML con ids diferentes, aumentando un valor dentro del `while`. Además he escrito un código más limpio y más claro. No me gusta esa mezcla horrible de HTML y PHP. Prefiero concatenar todo en una variable dentro de PHP y al final imprimirla.

Comment: Cedano, mil gracias también por la recomendación en cuanto a la limpides y claridad del código. Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero hace poco que estoy metiéndome en este fascinante mundo! Una última cosa para dar cerrada la cuestión: al definir los  id de los elementos en jquery, tendría que incluir la función dentro del bucle? o poner la variable generada por PHP en una única función? Si pudieras ampliar un poco con esa parte de código te lo agradecería, (yo mientras sigo intentado por mi cuenta) saludos!

Comment: @SantiagoGonzalez ignoro lo que quieres hacer en el interior.click de cada elemento en jQuery. Tú podrías en jQuery generar listeners dinámicos para el on.click de cada elemento con id= `hola`+`n`, pero eso solo tendría sentido en el caso de querer generar o asignar algo que sea secuencial, o sea, que sea como el `hola` que es fijo y luego solo le asignas un número. En cambio si por cada id debes asignar cosas que sean muy cambiantes no le veo sentido a generar ids dinámicos secuenciales.

Comment: mil gracias, sí, lo quería aplicar para algo secuencial, que muestre un div ocuto en cada elemento desplegado por el bucle. Me sirvió la lógica del bucle incremental para los ID, pues yo lo intentaba con números al azar. Asi que utilice el código que me diste para generar el código html con ids que vayan incrementando e hice lo mismo con el código jquery dentro del mismo bucle. Muchas gracias!!